# How do I convert these coordinates to real numbers?

Tags: python, coordinates, transform, openstreetmap, geopandas

I have something like this in two columns in one dataframe 
`data= pd.read_csv('xxxxxxxxxxxx.dat',delimiter=';',encoding='latin_1')` in python
Latitude=60°11.7765
Longitude=024°57.3073

And I would like to get this:

Latitude=60.1177....
Longitude=024.573....

Comment: Please show the code you used to create the dataframe, so we can understand what the data type is etc.

Comment: you can do `replace` on the string. `"60°11.76".replace('°",'')`

Comment: Do you *really* want the incorrect conversion of `60.1177`? `60°11.7765` looks like degree decimal minutes, which means the `11.7765` is minutes, not `.117764 degrees`

Comment: well, I just wanna to transforma those values 60°11.7765 in real numbers to put points in a map, Idk if I explain it in the good way

Comment: @renton if you are going to put them on a map you need to do the conversion properly. But to do that you need to know what you are starting with. If you know the locations you can try putting them in an online converted and see if the conversion maps to the correct place. For example, is `60°11.7765, 024°57.3073` supposed to be just north of Helsinki?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have to apologize. Your remark about the conversion was correct, I was confused by the question. The point is that the guy didn't even know what the final result looked like and I just told him how to get what he was asking for in his example, which was a simple substitution of char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you asked seems to want a simple substitution of some char, not a real conversion of coordinates. Thanks to the comments I understood that this ambiguity was due to the fact that you yourself did not have clear how to get the conversion. 
Among the different type of coordinates we find DDM (degrees decimal minutes) format. When you ask for "a real number" you are actually referring to the DD format (decimal degrees format, ex 13.41° N).
So in DDM the coordinate Latitude: 15°41.13 N consists of 3 values and a reference:

- D: degrees, here 15
- M: minutes, here 41
- S: seconds, here 13
- N or S: North or South (In longitude we have East or West)

As [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion), the formula for conversion from DDM to DD is

```
decimal degrees = degrees + (minutes/60 + seconds/3600)
```

I tried two online converters ([one](https://www.pgc.umn.edu/apps/convert/) and [two](https://www.directionsmag.com/site/latlong-converter/)) and it seems that the coordinates you wrote are in the DMM format. The only difference with the DDM format is that here the seconds are already divided by 60, so we can list:

- D: degrees, here 15
- M: minutes, here 41
- S: seconds/60, here 13
- N or S: North or South (In longitude we have East or West)

That means that the formula from DMM to DD is

```
decimal degrees = degrees + (minutes/60 + seconds/60)
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df_csv = pd.read_csv('file.dat',delimiter=';',encoding='UTF_8')
latitude = df_csv['Latitude'].astype('str')
for element in latitude:
    degree= float(element[:element.find('°')])
    minutes = float(element[(element.find('°')+1):(element.find('.'))])
    seconds= float(element[element.find('.'):])
    decimalDegrees=degree + minutes/60 + seconds/60
```

Input

```
Lat: 31°11.7765
```

Output

```
31.196275
```

In your coordinates you don't talk about any cardinal point. The rule is that if it is N or E the result is positive, if it's S or W the result is negative (-1 * output)